# Coffeescript range giving infinite results

Tags: coffeescript

This is outputting an infinite series of numbers. I need it to output an array of 10.

```
l_bound = "1000"
u_bound = l_bound + 10

range = [l_bound..u_bound]
console.log range
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `"1000" + 10` is `"100010"`... You should always try some simple debugging (like making sure variables contain what you think they contain) before posting questions to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `l_bound` equal to an actual integer instead of a string.

So you would have:

```
l_bound = 1000
u_bound = l_bound + 10

range = [l_bound..u_bound]
console.log range
```

The reason you were getting unexpected results before (thanks to @asawyer for the comment) is because `"1000" + 10 = "100010"`, or `100,010`, so your range was from 1000 to 100,010.

(For some reason, the code you provided logged `["1000", 1001, 1002, ...]`. If anyone could provide insight into why the first one is logged as a string, that would be interesting info)

Comment: Beat me to it, but in addition, it's not infinite results, it's 1000 to 100010, only 99,010 results.

Comment: Well, `..` is inclusive, so actually 99,011 results. But yeah... :)

Comment: RE Your lasts statement, it's pretty simple: The "range" is really just a JavaScript loop, which counts from the lower bound to the upper bound, pushing values onto an array. The loop's counting is implemented with `++`. The counting variable starts at `"1000"`, and stays there for the first iteration of the loop; when you `++` it at the beginning of the second iteration, it's converted to an integer. All subsequent values are integers.

Comment: The first one is logged as a string because it compiles to (leaving out some stuff that doesn't execute in this case) `for(var _i = l_bound;l_bound <= u_bound;_i++)`, so the first time `_i` is a string, and it doesn't get turned into a number until it is incremented for the first time (`_i++`).